# Best way to handle a nested for loop?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to save records to my database based on the selected options in a form.

The code i'm trying to use keeps telling me that j does not exists in the and j in previouscourselist.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for i in courselist and j in previouscourselist:
        requestsave(courselist and = i, previouscourselist= j)
```

Using the following below.  The records loops through correctly for the first part using for i in courselist .  previouscourselist will be wrote as a list [####,####,####] etc.  However, this is not what I want.

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in courselist
            requestsave(courselist = i, previouscourselist= previouscourselist)
```

What is the proper way to nest a forloop, so it loops through the courselist list and the previouscourselist?  Writing individual records where there is a different courselist and previouscourselist?

What i'm trying to accomplish is to have my `requestsave(courselist = i, and previouscourselist = j)`  So it's written like this:

```
CourseID   PreviousCourseID
2000       1001
2000       1015
2001       1001
2001       1015
2002       1001
2002       1015
```

Current using

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in courselist
            requestsave(courselist = i, previouscourselist= previouscourselist)
```

It writes the statement above to the database as

```
CourseID    PreviousCourse
2000        [1001, 1015]
2001        [1001, 1015]
2002        [1001, 1015]
```

Comment: `for i in courselist and j in previouscourselist` that won't work of course! what do you want? 2 nested loops?

Comment: If you need two nested loops then you have two nest them. That means two `for`s.

Comment: Alternatively, do you want `for i, j in zip(courselist, previouscourselist)`? It's impossible to know because you have not stated what you want to happen.

Comment: When sending the save to the database I want previouscourselist to have a forloop just like courselist, so yes i'd like to nest them in one statement for the write.

Comment: @DanielRoseman To call that nested would be outright wrong.  But sure, the Q is unclear.  Anything could be.

Comment: We're not sure what you're trying to do, or how you're stuck.  There are myriad examples and tutorials on line that demonstrate how to write nested `for` loops.  There are similarly many that show how to access two parallel sequences with a single loop (often with `zip` or `enumerate`).

Comment: I added what i'm attempting to do if that makes sense.  I thought i clarified that in the text above.  I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for i in courselist:
        for j in previouscourselist:
            requestsave(courselist=i, previouscourselist=j)
```

If this solves your issue:  There are other ways to achieve your goal, but if you did not know how to do this yet, then they are probably not a good alternative for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If an answer is useful, please *upvote* it (upward triangle left of it).  If an answer solves your issue, please *accept* it (check mark left of it).  (You may be obliged to wait for grace period before being able to do so, depending on reputation.)

Answer (score 3):

First, your syntax suggests you want to store the index rather than the item itself. If you want enumerations, the syntax will be:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    for item_course, i in enumerate(courselist):
        for item_prev_course, j in enumerate(previouscourselist):
            requestsave(courselist=i, previouscourselist=j)
```

Otherwise, if you want to store the item, it's a good idea to use better variable names so that your code is more easily interpreted by readers.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    for current_course in courselist:
        for prev_course in previouscourselist:
           requestsave(courselist=current_course, previouscourselist=prev_course)
```

If you want to join the lists into a dictionary where there is a one to one relationship, you can use the *zip()* function like so:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    course_dict = dict(zip(courselist, previouscourselist)
```

and then iterate along that dictionary

```
   for course, prev_course in course_dict:
       requestsave(courselist=course, previouscourselist=prev_course)
```